# Can the heart 'approach what it yearns', or must it 'approach what it yearns for'?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, word-usage

Paul Simon's lyrics

> ... how the heart approaches what it yearns...

has always seemed to me an incorrect usage, although it's difficult to state why. It seems to me that the verb *yearn*  requires an object in this case; thus the line should read

> ... how the heart approaches what it yearns for.

Any opinions?

Comment: Quite the opposite: _yearn_ doesn't normally take a direct object, which is why the lyrics seem awkward (they do to me as well). In Simon’s construction, there _is_ an object (“what”), but the verb normally takes a prepositional or infinitival phrase as its complement (“for [noun]” or “to [verb]”).

Comment: To a Brit, this is of a piece with his *Why don't you write me?*. I write letters, and I write them *to* people. I don't write people. But I realise this all sounds a bit pedantic to an American ear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we believe [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/yearn), the verb does not take an object:

> [NO OBJECT]
>   1Have an intense feeling of longing for something, typically something that one has lost or been separated from:
>   *she yearned for a glimpse of him*

And I believe it. With an object, a plausible sentence would be:

> *She yearned him.

However, *yearn for* something is prepositional verb, meaning that the preposition *for* is expected to be used in combination with the verb.
Alternatively, as JBJ mentions in his comment, you can use *yearn to* , of course.

Now for the sentence you quoted: *poetic license*.

Paul Simon is a pretty accomplished user of the English language (and I like understatements) but he's also a poet. There are several reasons to omit the *for* in the sentence you mention:

- the extra syllable breaks the meter
- the extra *for* would break the rhyme

Since this poet is a *singer*, rhyme and *especially* meter are very important to him. I think he quite naturally assumed that his audience would still understand what he meant, even if he let out a word that any listener would almost automatically fill in mentally.

Comment: Why he did it is clear. Is it correct? No. One can yearn, or one can yearn for something.

Comment: 'I yearn answer.' Plausible?

Comment: I'm pretty intolerant of strange new non-words and constructions, but 'how the heart approaches what it yearns' doesn't sound beyond the pale. There's probably a licensing of the transitive usage of 'yearn' in the OED, though it might be flagged 'archaic' say. However, 'I yearned a holiday' sounds outlandish and unacceptable. Unlike Yoda, who usually sounds outlandish but acceptable. 'Correct' is not as black-and-white as some people might imagine.

Comment: @jimerlin: if you would include _the answer you yearn_ in song lyrics that approach the linguistic skill and level of Paul Simon's usual work, yes, it would not just be plausible, it would be acceptable, understandable and for most people, it would hardly raise an eyebrow.

Comment: @oerkelens: Is english your native tongue? You don't have to sell Paul to me; I bought him ages ago. The question remains the same: Is it correct usage? One yearns, intransitively. Another asks, 'What do you yearn?', but the question has no meaning. 'Why do you yearn?' or 'When?', but not 'What?, as that invokes an object, something yearned FOR (i haven't found the italics mode yet). Not to be negative, but most people's eyebrow movement is scant indication.

Comment: @jimerlin I answered already that it is not _correct_ usage, but poetic license. As to whether it is _acceptable_ poetic license, several people already have agreed it _is_.